# Keep a dot while clicking in the cube for drawing a line

Tags: three.js

Working on the task for connecting two cubes by a line where I want to keep a dot while clicking in the cube and another cube where the dot represents as the line starting point and ending point. Here's the code and thanks in advance.
The code has two cubes which joints each other with a line in a click where I want to represent a dot in the start and end line

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(),
    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersected, lineObjects = [],
    objects = [];

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500);
    camera.position.set(5, 15, 10);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown, false);
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);


    var cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    cube1.position.set(2, 5, 5)
    scene.add(cube1);

}

function lineObj(pointStart, pointEnd) {
    var lineGeom = new THREE.Geometry();
    lineGeom.vertices.push(pointStart.clone());
    lineGeom.vertices.push(pointEnd.clone());
    var lineMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: "red"
    });
    line = new THREE.Line(lineGeom, lineMat);
    return line;
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -((event.clientY) / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
    // var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children,true);
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        var found = intersects[0].object;
        if (found != intersected) {
            if (lineObjects.length > 0) {
                var line = lineObj(lineObjects[0].position, found.position);
                scene.add(line);
                lineObjects[0].material.color.setHex(lineObjects[0].userData.oldColor);
                intersected = null;
                lineObjects = [];
            } else {
                found.userData.oldColor = found.material.color.getHex();
                found.material.color.set(0x00FF00);
                intersected = found;
                lineObjects.push(found);
            }
        } else {
            found.material.color.setHex(found.userData.oldColor);
            intersected = null;
            lineObjects = [];
        }
    }
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/16929/